# viewing the images problem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using ASP.Net and VB.Net

Code

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "c:\Blue hills.jpg"
```

The above code is not viewing the image when i clicked the button.

How to solve this problem.

Need Code Help

Comment: What is the type of `Image1`? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and improve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be referencing the local file path - you should set the `ImageUrl` to be the URL on the webserver - for example, if you had the file in the root of your website, you'd reference it as:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "/Blue%20hills.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you are supplying to the ImageUrl property is a file path and not a Url.
Ideally you should have a folder in your ASP.NET application that holds your image files which you can then reference with either a relative or absolute Url path i.e:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "/Content/Images/Blue hills.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show pictures from the server disk that are outside of the website root, you have to build "proxy" page. For example call it `ShowImage.aspx` and it will get the picture name on the URL.

Then you'll have such code

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "ShowImage.aspx?image=Blue hills.jpg"
```

And the code for ShowImage.aspx code behind:

```cs
string imageName = Request.QueryString["image"] + "";
if (imageName.Length == 0 || imageName.Contains("/") || imageName.Contains("\\") || !imageName.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg"))
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid image requested");
}
else
{
    string strFullPath = "C:\\" + imageName;
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.WriteFile(strFullPath);
}
Response.End();
```

This is `C#` but should be simple enough to translate into `VB.NET` as well.

Edit: added basic validation that verify that user does not try to fetch files from different directory and allows only `.jpg` files.

Comment: Of course, this opens up soem massive security holes, and actually does part of what the webserver would do itself (although that would also handle content expiration as well)

Comment: @Rowland: So you say that if someone want to show images that sit in other place than the root, he must not do that? I don't think it's true sorry. Regarding security it's simple to check if the given name is valid and existing image. No risk here.

Comment: @Shadow I'm saying that your code could deliver any file from the file system (as long as file permissions don't get in the way) - it may be delivered with the wrong MIME type, but it could still deliver it. For example, if someone were to call ShowImage.aspx?image=Inetpub\wwwroot\Default.aspx (or the web.config or...)

Comment: @Rowland - validation is possible, if the OP is interested I can guide him on this. Trying to send `aspx` or config files as images will just show broken image in the browser, but you're right that it's not a good idea to let it happen.

Comment: @Rowland - added some basic validation to my post.

Comment: @Shadow naughty people like hackers won't be necessarily be using a browser though, which is partly why it would be an issue -- My original point about getting the webserver to do this still holds - why reinvent the wheel, when you've demonstrated quite how easy it is to introduce a security hole...

Answer (score 0):

```
Image1.ImageUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "/"+ "Images" + "/"  + "Blue hills.jpg";
```

but as said before you can't reference a local file like this , except u use HttpHandler.

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm